# Eliminating duplicates in an array Javascript/ AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

Scenario 1

An API that i call returns an array with duplicates.

```
var array1 = [{id:1, foo:23},{id:1, foo:24},{id:1, foo:22},{id:2, foo:26},{id:3, foo:26}]; //example
```

Question 1 -> how do I eliminate the duplicates to get a desired result of:

```
var array2 = [{id:1, foo:23 },{id:2, foo:26},{id:3, foo:26}];
```

---

Scenario 2

In my pagination i would call a new set of array

```
var array1 = [{id:2, foo:27},{id:2, foo:28},{id:3, foo:29},{id:4, foo:28},{id:5, foo:23}]; //example
```

i then do a foreach loop, to push it to array2.

```
var array2 = [{id:1, foo:23},{id:2, foo:27},{id:3, foo:27}];

angular.forEach(array1, function(a){
              array2.push(a)                           
         });
```

Question 2 ->  How do i prevent an object in array1 that exists in array2 from getting pushed.

desired result:

```
var array2 = [{id:1, foo:23},{id:2, foo:27},{id:3, foo:27},{id:4, foo:28},{id:5, foo:23}]
```

Comment: Take a look at Lodash https://lodash.com/

Comment: Your question is supposed to be about fixing what you have written, not asking to write the code for you.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest Lodash library (https://lodash.com), it simplifies life alot.

If you are willing to use Lodash it has `uniq` function (https://lodash.com/docs#uniq).

```
var myUniqObjectArray = _.uniq(array1, 'id');
```

Where `array1` is the source array, `id` is the property based on which all objects are compared.

Comment: I have another field that is not consistent, so i have to base it by the id. I edited my code please check thank you

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Even when changing your sample, the proposed solution returns the expected result. So, ``_.uniq(array1, 'id');`` will give the result ``[{id:1, foo:23 },{id:2, foo:26},{id:3, foo:26}];`` (array2).  Maybe I get it wrong and new base data and expected result are in order.